# How to get the answer choice

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

This is a GRE quantitative question. 
Without hints, how to pick the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$3.7=\frac{37}{10}$$

And $37$ and $10$ have no common divisors, so this is the most simplified form possible for this fraction. Thus, every other form for this fraction comes by multiplying this one by one above and below by the same integer. You can use that fact to analyze the possible natures of $a, b, c$ and $d$.